# TFS 2010 Reporting Service - All reports contain no data

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, tfs

All reports in the TFS reporting service are empty, even though the collection contains numerous work items (bugs, iterations, task).

[image]

I've deleted and created/re-built both the tfs_Analysis and tfs_Warehouse databases, but still no luck.

Examining the Tfs_Warehouse database I find data in many of the tables, but the table DimWorkItem does not contain any rows. I suspect this may be the cause of the issue with empty reports, but not sure why this table has not been populated.

Not quite sure where to go next in order to resolve this issue.

Comment: Has the team been logging their progress on these tasks?

Comment: Yes, it's a database that's been in use for at least one year

Comment: Did you backup and restore your TFS database recently and did you get any related error info in event view?

Comment: The database was at one time restored (manually) from a crashed db, which the content was recovered. That may of course be part of the problem. I was hoping to find a way to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to the Warehouse Control Web Service, and check the Processing Status, then manually process the data warehouse relational database by following article [Manually Process the Data Warehouse and Analysis Services Cube for Team Foundation Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400237(v=vs.100).aspx).

To access the Warehouse Control Web Service:

1. Log on to the application-tier server.
2. Open Internet Explorer, type the following string in the Address bar, and then press ENTER:

-

```
http://localhost:8080/VirtualDirectory/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/WarehouseControlService.asmx
```

Comment: I've done that already, the status for the services are fine. They all run with success. Though the table dimworkitem is not populated